# REGEX conversion for iOS time

Tags: ios

I have this REGEX on webbased system and would like to use it on iOS Objective-C so it needs some conversion. Its to check a time format in 24 hour and am/pm. Could someone help me?

```
#^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]?( )?([aApP][mM]))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]?))$#
```

Comment: for this why you need regex?

Comment: I have a check on textfield input and use regex to validate it. It works perfect but now i need this REGEX to work for me on iOS

Comment: do you have date in NSDate or NSString type? Why you are allowing user to enter date on textfield, you can use UIDatePicker instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your regex with  **NSPredicate**

```
NSString *regex = @"^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]?( )?([aApP][mM]))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]?))$";
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

BOOL status = [test evaluateWithObject:value];
```